# Representing a tic tac toe board in computer memory,

Tags: tic-tac-toe

I am trying to solve this problem: Design a method for representing the state of a tic-tac-toe board in computer memory. Can you fit your representation into three bytes?

This is from a textbook without solutions, thank you!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A good programmer can do it in 28 bits (9 records of 3 states), a crazy one would use only 15 bits (3 records of 27 states). Both are less than 24 bits.

Comment: And no, you should do this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state of a Tic-Tac-Toe board can be encoded using 3 bytes as follows.

To represent the state of each cell, 3 states are necessary, namely `X`, `O` and `undefined`. 3 states can be represented by 2 bits (2 bits can in fact represent 4 states, but only 3 are needed here - on the other hand, 1 bit is insufficient).

There are 9 cells in total, so in total

```
2 * 9 = 18
```

bits are necessary to represent the board. 18 bits can be encoded in 3 bytes (which in total have 24 bits, which means that 6 bits are not needed).

Answer (score 1):

A Tic-Tac-Toe board consist of 9 fields. Each field can take 3 states: Empty, Circle, Cross. To represent each state you need 2 bits: 00, 01, 10.

With two bits for each field, you can easily represent whole board in 3 bytes, by using two bits as each field, and each byte as row of board.